# Android dependent library can not access R class of dependency library

Tags: android

In android studio I have two library projects A and B. B is trying to access a String resource value that's in project A's strings.xml The code used looks like this

```
context.getString(com.myproject.libraryA.R.string.prefname);
```

Error received is package name com.myproject.libraryA.R does not exist.

B is using A as dependency module.

Why this is failing or wrong way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your A module is a **Library Module**. Then all A module's resource will be built into its **R** class and merged to B module's **R** class. That means you can get `R.string.prefname` by both `com.myproject.libraryA.R.string.prefname` and `com.myproject.libraryB.R.string.prefname`.

I suggest you do "***File***->**Invalidate Caches**" or "***Build***->**Rebuild Project**", it should work.

You can also refer [Managing Projects Overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) to see more detail.